# Should we use 'of' when describing quantities with 'score' and 'dozen'?

Tags: nouns, determiners

> There are **two score of books** which are lying unused in the library.

Why is  **two score of books** used instead of **two score books**?  What is the difference between them? Similarly can we use **five dozen of bananas** instead of **five dozen bananas**?

Example: He bought five dozen of bananas.

Comment: Please provide a source for your quotation.

Comment: It is from my grammar book in India @KateBunting. What’s your opinion on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two score books and two score of books](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/246180/two-score-books-and-two-score-of-books)

Answer (score 3):

"Two score of books" sounds wrong to me. But "two score books" would be perfectly acceptable.

A famous example of this phrasing is Abraham Lincoln's Gettysburg Address:

> Four score and seven years ago...

This is obviously slightly archaic, but so is the use of "score" generally; I've never heard it in normal speech.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is wrong: it should be 'two score*s* of books'; you need the plural there.

The 'of' is used because 'score' isn't exactly synonymous with 'twenty', rather, it means a *set* of (about) twenty things. Therefore, the word 'of' is used, just like you would say 'two sets of books'. Another example: you say 'hundred books' but 'hundreds *of* books'.

'dozen' *also* means a set of twelve, but it seems to have evolved into a proper [cardinal numeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_numeral). Therefore, you say 'five dozen' instead of 'five dozens', and omit the 'of'. 'He bought five dozen bananas.' would be correct.

Comment: However, if we don't specify a number with the plural, then we do use *of*: *He bought **dozens of** bananas*. Omitting the preposition in that case would be incorrect.

Comment: @JasonBassford yes; the same holds for other numerals (*thousands of bananas*).

Comment: You may say "hundreds of books", but not "two hundreds of books". "Two scores of books" is wrong in the same way.

Comment: @hobbs Is correct. "scores" in the plural is more like "lots", rather than a specific number.